# How to specify type information for Iterator::filter_map?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let a = ["1", "2", "lol"];
    let cnt = a.iter().filter_map(|s| s.parse().ok()).count();
}
```

Error message

```
<anon>:3:24: 3:34 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]

<anon>:3     let cnt = a.iter().filter_map(|s| s.parse().ok()).count();
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried to specify types for `filter_map()` but was not successful. If possible, I also want to know why compiler does not complain if I remove the `count()` method.

Comment: Removing `.count()` has the same error, [as far as I see](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5a204c4e748c6cb5138533947591e0cd&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know the result type of the parse, because the way you wrote it the code could work for any type. You need to annotate this method call specifically: `s.parse::<i32>().ok()`

Comment: Could it be done elsewhere? Such as `filter_map::<i32, ?>()` I'm not sure what the "?" part should be.

Comment: You can do `filter_map::<i32, _>(...)`, and the compiler will infer the closure type.  You can't explicitly name the concrete type of a closure, though.

Comment: However, I would claim that explicitly specifying the parameter for `parse` is more idiomatic and readable, since that's really where the ambiguity comes from.